# snmptrap unsigned type not working as expected

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I am using snmpV3 adapter and passing V2 traps to it by using commands as below. It looks like the range for type u (i.e. unsigned) is upto (2^31) - 1 (i.e. 2147483647). I was expecting it to be (2^32) - 1 (i.e. 4294967295).

`snmptrap -c public -v 2c clm-pun-009642 '' 1.3.6.1.4.1.20006.1.0.5 1.3.6.1.4.1.12345.1 u 2147483647`

Above command generates following log:

`trace:  ..\..\snmplib\snmp_api.c, 5293:
dumph_recv:             Value
dumpx_recv:              42 04 7F FF FF FF
dumpv_recv:                UInteger:    2147483647 (0x7FFFFFFF)`

Where as for:

`snmptrap -c public -v 2c clm-pun-009642 '' 1.3.6.1.4.1.20006.1.0.5 1.3.6.1.4.1.12345.1 u 2147483648`

Above command generates following log:

`enter code heretrace:  ..\..\snmplib\snmp_api.c, 5293:
dumph_recv:             Value
dumpx_recv:              42 05 00 80 00 00 00
dumpv_recv:                UInteger:    -2147483648 (0x80000000)`

Refer to:
http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmptrap.html

I am using net-snmp v5.5.

Is this the correct behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: net-snmp v5.5 is pretty old. Try the latest and see if this is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered various problems with net-snmp over the years. This is apparently one more. The standards are quite clear. RFC 2578 defines Unsigned32 as follows:

> -- an unsigned 32-bit quantity
>   -- indistinguishable from Gauge32 Unsigned32 ::=
>       [APPLICATION 2]
>           IMPLICIT INTEGER (0..4294967295)

As noted, this is identical to Gauge32, which is identical to Gauge in SNMPv1 (RFC 1155):

> Gauge ::=
>       [APPLICATION 2]
>           IMPLICIT INTEGER (0..4294967295)

The encoding is correct; all integers within SNMP are encoded as signed, meaning a value above 2^31-1 must be encoded in 5 bytes. Thus the proper translation of the encoding is:

```
42               Type: Gauge32 or Unsigned32
05               Length: 5 bytes
00 80 00 00 00   Value: 2^31
```

net-snmp is incorrectly decoding the value.

Comment: Where does 42 come from? I've searched all over the internet and can't seem to find anywhere where these numbers are defined. The specs also don't define 42. Is there any document that maps SNMP types (the custom asn extensions) to these magic numbers?